# i want the socket("ipAddress",port) to try for connection until the serversocket is not online in java

Tags: java, android, sockets

Here is my code `Socket s = new Socket("ipaddress",port);` but the problem is that if serversocket not found then application not responding error occur.
I want the socket to try for connection even if the serversocket is offline.
then connect the serversocket whenever the serversocket is online.
I tryied the try and catch blog but ANR error occurs.

Comment: You can try catch the exception and wrap the whole thing into a loop... `public Socket openSocket() { while(true) { try { Socket socket = new Socket("ipaddress",port); return socket; } catch(IOException e) { //log or whatever } } }` But of course that's probably a pretty bad idea.

Comment: i did the same thing but when the control reaches to try and catch block it get the famous error application not responding

Comment: Good you did not post any code. Now we can talk and talk.

Comment: Of course the application is not responding. It's an infinite loop, what do you expect? The application is busy waiting for something... That's why I said it's a bad idea, as you would have to do the whole thing asynchronously for it to work smoothly.

Comment: Even if it is an infinitive loop the application should respond as that code will run in an AsyncTask or thread. He said his app is crashing.